# VBA Get number From HTML

Tags: html, excel, vba

The objetive is to extract the XBT/USD last value from this website: https://www.kraken.com/charts
I got this code from another question and tried to edit it for the need without success.

```
 Option Explicit
    Sub Get_Number()

 'Open website
    Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    IE.Visible = True

    IE.Navigate "https://www.kraken.com/charts"

    Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop
'Clicl on XBT/USD in order to change the value from EUR to USD
    IE.Document.getElementById("pairselect-button").Click
    IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("currpairs")(1).Click

'Extract USD last value
    Dim kfc As Integer
    Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
        For Each oHTML_Element In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("div")
            If oHTML_Element.className = "val.mono" Then
                kfc = oHTML_Element.Value
            End If
        Next
    Range("A2").Value = kfc
    End Sub
```

HTML code according to inspect element

```
<div class="val mono" data-val="2324.999" name="last" style="color: rgb(0, 178, 86);">$2,738.5<span class="deczeros">00</span></div>
```

After this, I got 0 on A2 intead of $2,738.5

Thanks in advance for your valuable help.

Comment: It seems this line is wrong since the class name is "val mono" and not "val.mono" `If oHTML_Element.className = "val.mono" Then`

Answer (score 2):

Main reason you got 0 was that kfc never equaled anything other than 0. I changed val.mono to val mono and I changed the variable type to string instead of integer. The code below in the best way I know how with late binding.

```
Sub Get_Number()

    'Open website
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim event_created As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True

    IE.navigate "https://www.kraken.com/charts"

    Do While IE.readyState <> 4
    Application.Wait TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Loop
    Application.Wait TimeValue("00:00:01")
    'Clicl on XBT/USD in order to change the value from EUR to USD
    Set event_created = IE.document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
    event_created.initEvent "click", True, False
    DoEvents
    IE.document.getElementById("pairselect-button").dispatchEvent event_created
    IE.document.getElementsByClassName("currpairs")(1).dispatchEvent event_created

    'Extract USD last value
    Dim kfc As String
    Dim oHTML_Element As Object
    Dim divs As Object
    Set divs = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("div")
    For Each oHTML_Element In divs
        If oHTML_Element.className = "val mono" Then
            kfc = oHTML_Element.textContent
        End If
    Next
    Range("A2").Value = kfc
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of extracting it from the HTML, that website has an api access which should work more quickly.

Note that I used early-binding in the code below, but you can always switch it to late-binding if you need to.

Also, I chose to return both the last trade and the time of that trade (in UTC time).  I used Regular Expressions to extract these.

There are other public api calls you can use.  For example, if you are interested only the price of the last trade, and not the time, you can get Ticker Information.

See the [Kraken API Help Page](https://www.kraken.com/help/api) for further information.

The results are written into `A1` and `B1`, but you could set up a routine that writes the results sequentially into subsequent rows.

Perhaps something like:

```
Option Explicit
Sub LastTrade()
'Microsoft Windows HTTP Services 5.1
'Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5

    Dim httpRequest As WinHttpRequest
    Dim sResponse As String
    Dim sInfo As String

    Dim RE As RegExp, MC As MatchCollection

    Dim D As Double

Const sUrl As String = "https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Trades"
sInfo = "?pair=XBTUSD"

Set httpRequest = New WinHttpRequest
httpRequest.Open "Get", sUrl & sInfo

httpRequest.Send
httpRequest.WaitForResponse

sResponse = httpRequest.ResponseText

Set RE = New RegExp
With RE
    .Global = False
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .Pattern = "\[""(\d+\.\d+)"",[^,]+,(\d+\.\d+)[^]]+]],""last"""

    If .Test(sResponse) = True Then
        Set MC = .Execute(sResponse)
        [a1].NumberFormat = "$#,###.000"
        [a1] = MC(0).SubMatches(0)

        D = MC(0).SubMatches(1) 'Unix time
        D = D / 86400 + CDbl(#1/1/1970#)

        With [b1]
            .NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:ss"
            .Value = D
        End With

    Else
        [a1] = Right(sResponse, 100)
    End If
End With

Set httpRequest = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a little bit slow with that code but worked. Also I found that the value was giving the WEIGHTED AVG then I corrected to LAST changing "`getElementsByTagName("div")`" by "`getElementsByName("last")`" and also corrected with your string suggestion and worked with innertext  as below:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Get_Number1()

 'Open website
    Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "https://www.kraken.com/charts"
    Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop
'Click on XBT/USD in order to change the value from EUR to USD
    IE.Document.getElementById("pairselect-button").Click
    IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("currpairs")(1).Click

''Extract USD last value
    Dim kfc As String
    Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
        For Each oHTML_Element In IE.Document.getElementsByName("last")
            If oHTML_Element.className = "val mono" Then
                kfc = oHTML_Element.innerText
            End If
        Next
    Debug.Print kfc
End Sub
```

Thanks very much